# Orthogonal decompositions using the modred module in python

Tags: python, class, object

I am trying to write a code for orthogonal decompositions using the modred module in python. My custom vector class is defined as:

```
class CustomVector(mr.Vector):

    def __init__(self, data_array):
        self.data_array = data_array
    def inner_product(self, other):
        return np.dot(self.data_array, other.data_array)
```

Another class definition is given as:

```
class CustomVecHandle(mr.VecHandle):

    def __init__(self, vec_path, base_handle=None, scale=None):
        mr.VecHandle.__init__(self, base_handle, scale)
        self.vec_path = vec_path
        self.res_path = result_root
    def _get(self):
        # read in the values
        print ("reading data from {}".format(self.vec_path))
        reader = vtk.vtkPolyDataReader()
        reader.SetFileName(self.vec_path)
        reader.Update()
        data = dsa.WrapDataObject(reader.GetOutput()).PointData['U']
        return CustomVector(data)
```

And another function is defined outside all classes as:

```
 def inner_product(v1, v2):
     return v1.inner_product(v2)
```

I have created a list object as:

```
vec_handles = [CustomVecHandle(os.path.join(data_root, d, "{}_0.vtk".format(d)))for d in dirs]
```

This vec_handles is given as the input for a function in the modred module, and the following operations are done in the main modred code:

```
test_vec = vec_handles

IP_burn = self.inner_product(test_vec, test_vec)
```

But when I run the following code I am getting the error that:

```
  File "/home/sindhuja/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/modred/vectorspace.py", line 495, in compute_symmetric_inner_product_mat
    IP_burn = self.inner_product(test_vec, test_vec)    
  File "podd.py", line 58, in inner_product
    return v1.inner_product(v2)    
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'inner_product'
```

I understand that the created vec_handles is a list of objects for the class CustomVecHandle. And trying to get the method using .innerproduct(test_vec) is not possible but since it's the code of the modred module, I don't think that's wrong. So how do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
vec_handles = [CustomVecHandle(os.path.join(data_root, d, "{}_0.vtk".format(d)))for d in dirs]

IP_Burn = []
for i in range(len(test_vec):
    for j in range(i+1 , len(test_vec)):
        IP_Burn.append(test_vec[i]._get().inner_product(test_vec[j]._get()))
```

**Note**:

1) You dont need a private get method use get() instead of _get()

2) you can construct a list of customVec objects rather than customVecHandle objects

```
vec_handles = [CustomVecHandle(os.path.join(data_root, d, "{}_0.vtk".format(d))).get() for d in dirs]

IP_Burn = []
for i in range(len(test_vec):
    for j in range(i+1 , len(test_vec)):
        IP_Burn.append(test_vec[i].inner_product(test_vec[j]))
```